# Why users are providing expired link?

Tags: discussion, answers, hyperlinks, dead-links

I see many  old answers contains  expired links. Whenever I click on a  link it show that links has expired.

I'm not getting why users  are providing expired links in an answer?

Comment: A relevant, Google-able phrase is "[link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)".

Comment: A lot of users with high reputation like to post expired links.

Comment: @jasmine Before assuming users posted expired links, check the [wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/) *at the time of the post*.

Comment: And what do you do when you come across one of these expired links, jasmine? Do you leave a helpful comment, noting that the link has expired, so that maybe the user who left it will come back to repair the damage? Do you try to improve the situation in some other way?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Sir    that's not a problem.    Actually ,  i thought that  users were intentionally providing expired links

Comment: @GerryMyerson  sir Also,  I've noticed  that most of the old users are  not active  so i think  it will  be useless to comment  on an answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is not that they provide expired links: they provide live links, time passes, and the links then expire. This happens very often, and that's why we prefer to avoid depending on links when answering questions on the site, unless they are reliable. Even in this case, it is much preferred if the answer does not depend on the link to be useful, and it is self-contained. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19818/answers-with-links-or-references) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13630/should-external-links-be-used-in-answer-posts-since-the-links-might-be-broken-l) for further discussion.